# android Espresso- toast message assertions not working with sdk 30

Tags: android, android-espresso, assertion, matcher, android-toast

this simple check is working on sdk 29 but not on sdk 30:

onView(withText(R.string.text)).inRoot( withDecorView(not(mActivityRule.activity.window.decorView))) .check(matches(isDisplayed()))

I get androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingRootException.

can anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Espresso can't reliably assert toast messages. Use `uiAutomator` alongwith espresso for asserting toasts.

```
    fun checkToast(msg: String) {
        val uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
        uiDevice.waitForIdle()
        org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(uiDevice.hasObject(By.text(msg)))
    }
```

Comment: still not working (on api 29 and 30).

This is working on 29 and not on 30:
onView(withText(R.string.text)).inRoot( withDecorView(not(mActivityRule.activity.window.decorView))) .check(matches(isDisplayed()))

Comment: For me this is not even working on Android 28 (did not test with older versions). Not even UI Automator Viewer can detect the toast (even though I can see the message in the screenshot).

Answer (score 0):

Accourding to the comments for this [issue](https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/803) in github. You can see that toast matching in sdk 30 is not working with anybody